# How to create a CXF web service in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, web-services, cxf

I'm new to webservices. I'm trying to create a webservice using CXF 3.0.1 framework in Eclipse. I'm finding few issues like "selection must be WSDL " error message while creating new webservice for a selected class file and could not proceed further. Have anyone faced similar issue with this CXF version ?

Answer (score 0):

I can only answer to the question you ask directly:

If you start generating a web service from a class file you are creating a bottom up web service. For this you will have to select Bottom Up Java bean Web Service in Web service type in the eclipse wizard. If you select Top down Java bean Web Service it wants to create a web service starting from a wsdl, thus the error you mentioned if you enter a class there.